# Разместить элементы в Tabcontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Всем доброго дня!
Недавно начал изучать WPF и столкнулся с проблемой.
Задача:
В динамически созданной вкладке TabControl разместить элементы управления Checkbox, Label и тд.
Есть цикл который при полученных данных генерирует TabItem.

```
foreach (var device in devices)
{
  CheckBox с = new CheckBox();
                с.Content = "Press me";
                TabItem item = new TabItem();
                item.Name = device.Name;
                item.Header = device.Name;
                item.Content = с;
                tabControl.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Вот этим кодом я могу создать вкладку, задать Header и добавить один элемент, а как добавить несколько?
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Для однотипных повторяющихся наборов контролов надо использовать заранее созданный контейнер -> `UserControl`. И в цикле тогда надо будет просто добавлять на `TabItem` заготовленный  `UserControl`.

Comment: хороший совет, покапаю в эту сторону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с UserControl

```
 foreach (var device in devices)
                {
                    SettingsMenu st = new SettingsMenu();\\(собственно загрузка самого контрола)
                    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(st);
                    var item = new TabItem();
                    item.Name = device.Name;
                    item.Header = device.Name;
                    item.Content = stackPanel;
                    tabControl.Items.Add(item);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  foreach (var device in devices)
    {
                    CheckBox ffff = new CheckBox();
                    CheckBox btn = new CheckBox();
                    btn.Content = "Press me";
                    btn.Width = 75;
                    btn.Height = 50;
                    var stackPanel = new StackPanel();
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(btn);
                    stackPanel.Children.Add(ffff);
                    var item = new TabItem();
                    item.Name = device.Name;
                    item.Header = device.Name;
                    item.Content = stackPanel;
                    tabControl.Items.Add(item);

    }
```

Comment: stackPanel.Children.Add(Вот тут можно добавлять всё что угодно)